# Min Brands for Msku's

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data which has columns: `City` and `Brand`. I want to find out the minimum No. of brands which will cover all the cities.

```
City    Brands
C1      B1
C2      B2
C3      B1
C4      B1
C5      B3
C6      B6
C7      B9
C8      B1
C9      B4
C10     B5
C5      B2
C6      B2
C7      B4
C8      B4
C9      B1
C10     B4
```

So, in this case, the solution is `(B1, B2, B4)` because these 3 brands can cover all the cities.

Comment: This is an instance of the classic minimum set cover problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Answer (score 0):

I see a flag with Wikipedia math formulas.... They scare me =]]
But if you ask me how I will sorted then this is the answer.

```py
# Here will save some 20 random list of citys and brand (I think your look same)
cityList = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C10', 'C10', 'C7', 'C1', 'C10', 'C8', 'C5', 'C3', 'C3', 'C10']
brandList = ['B10', 'B5', 'B8', 'B7', 'B5', 'B3', 'B4', 'B7', 'B3', 'B7', 'B10', 'B1', 'B5', 'B7', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B2', 'B4', 'B4']

# Here we will make a temporary sort
tempCitysCount = []
tempSortedByBrands = {}
# Here we make a dictionare what will sort citys by brand
sortedByBrands = {}

index = 0
for i in brandList:
    if not i in tempSortedByBrands:
        tempSortedByBrands[i] = cityList[index]
    else:
        citys = tempSortedByBrands[i] + ";" + cityList[index]
        tempSortedByBrands[i] = citys

    index += 1

print("Sorted list of the brands:", sorted(brandList))

# First we try to count how many citiys are with the same brand
try:
    for brand, city in tempSortedByBrands.items():
        if ";" in city:
            x = city.split(";")
            tempCitysCount.append(f"{len(x)}: {brand}")
        else:
            tempCitysCount.append(f"1: {brand}")
finally:
    # Finally we sort the list reversed (from biger number to smaller one)
    # And we print it to see if is what we espect
    print("\nSorted count of the brands:", sorted(tempCitysCount, reverse=True))

# Now we try to put all information sorted
try:
    for _ in sorted(tempCitysCount, reverse=True):
        x = _.split(": ")
        for brand, city in tempSortedByBrands.items():
            if brand == x[1]:
                sortedByBrands[brand] = city
finally:
    # After is done, just print sorted list
    print("\nMost popular brands are:")
    for i,j in sortedByBrands.items():
        if ";" in j:
            j0 = j.split(";")
            count_c = 0
            city_list = ""
            for c in j0:
                count_c += 1
                if count_c == len(j0):
                    city_list = f"{city_list} and {c}"
                else:
                    city_list = f"{city_list}, {c}"

            if city_list[:2] == ", ":
                city_list = city_list[2:]

            print(f"{i} can be fount in {city_list}")

        else:
            print(f"{i} can be found in {j}")
```

The output is here:

```
Sorted list of the brands: ['B1', 'B10', 'B10', 'B2', 'B3', 'B3', 'B4', 'B4', 'B4', 'B4', 'B5', 'B5', 'B5', 'B5', 'B7', 'B7', 'B7', 'B7', 'B7', 'B8']

Sorted count of the brands: ['5: B7', '4: B5', '4: B4', '2: B3', '2: B10', '1: B8', '1: B2', '1: B1']

Most popular brands are:
B7 can be fount in C4, C8, C10, C1 and C5
B5 can be fount in C2, C5, C7 and C8
B4 can be fount in C7, C10, C3 and C10
B3 can be fount in C6 and C9
B10 can be fount in C1 and C10
B8 can be found in C3
B2 can be found in C3
B1 can be found in C10
```